# EWS Error while trying to send mail

Tags: exchangewebservices

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The request failed schema validation: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:EmailAddress' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:NonEmptyStringType' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException webException)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.Save(FolderId parentFolderId)
   at EWS_Mail_Object_New.New_Mail1(String UserName, String Password, String MailID, String Service_URL, String recipient, String Subject, String message_body, String cc, Boolean SaveAsDraft, DataTable Attachments, DataTable Inline_Attachments, String bcc, Boolean& Success, String& Message)
```

Comment: Please post your code and tag the language used. You need to give your question some context

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going by this line in the error message as you have not posted your code:

> EWS_Mail_Object_New.New_Mail1(String UserName, String Password, String MailID, String Service_URL, String recipient, String Subject,
>   String message_body, String cc, Boolean SaveAsDraft, DataTable
>   Attachments, DataTable Inline_Attachments, String bcc, Boolean&
>   Success, String& Message)

The error means that an email address is not being set I.E it's an empty string.
Debug and check that the `recipient`, `cc` and `bcc` have an email address set.

Comment: @user9334708 did this help you resolve your issue? If so, please mark as answer